# Negative implications of network trips?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networking, network-programming

I have a large (~ 150 MB) CSV output file that I need to translate from Spanish to English via API (e.g. Microsoft, Amazon, etc.) on an as-needed basis.

There's 25 columns, and many 100k rows.

Of those 25 columns, only about half need to be translated, as other half are numeric data.

Microsoft & Amazon charge for translation a per-character basis, so rather than translating the entire file, I thought about just picking the 12 columns that actually need to be translated, and translating them on an element-by-element basis

The problem is that this leads to several hundred thousand network API calls to Microsoft's translation API -- one for each element of each column. While there's nothing inherently "wrong", I can't help but feel there's something inefficient about it.

**What are the negative implications of a script that does several hundred thousand network trips to call an API?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the negative implications of a script that does several
> hundred thousand network trips to call an API?

Beyond the possible pricing implications, the most straightforward implication is increased latency. Calls over the network are one of the slowest things a program can do.

While the time to execute a cpu instruction can be measured in nanoseconds, network calls are typically measured in tens or hundreds of milliseconds. That's a difference of x100,000,000.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Would you feel a hybrid approach would be worth considering? Maybe an entire column is 10 MB when spliced out into its own CSV. I could then that, but I feel that opens a new can of worms & discussion on the implications of sending large files. Thoughts?

Comment: Sure, it could make sense to pick a middle ground between sending value individually, and sending everything at once. However, there's also code complexity to consider.
My advice is to not lose track of the problem at hand.
If sending every value to the API individually is fast enough for your use case and is simpler to write (and more importantly-easier to read and understand), start there.